# How to check new R# rules violations for my commit?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, resharper

We have a VS solution, working with SVN as revision control. In our solution we use resharper rules to check code quality. 
How can we know if the changes that we made create new violations of this rules? Do you know any automated way?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some Continuous Integration server like Jenkins or TFS? If not, set it up.

For ReSharper, there are CommandLine Tools available (you don't even need an extra license for them). You can call them with your automatic builds, e.g.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CommandLineTools\InspectCode.exe" /o=Resharper.Result.xml /toolset=12.0 YourSolution.sln
```

and then publish its report.

Do not forget to check-in your `.DotSettings` file if you changed some rules!

Comment: Yes we have a Jenkins server and a sonarqube instance that runs this quality checks. But we want to test locally before commit if we add some violations with the uncommited changes.